# Import specified cells from all present Excel worksheets using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an excel file that has multiple sheets (one new sheet added every month). I am trying to build a package in SSIS that will loop through each sheet that is present in the file - regardless of how many sheets there are or what they're named - and import data from a range of cells. For example, if it's March, I need the package to loop through all the worksheets in the file ('Jan Pick Up', 'Feb Pick Up', 'March Pick Up' in this case) and import cells A6:P57 from each worksheet into a preexisting SQL Server table.

Does anyone have any tips? I've tried looking around quite a bit but can only seem to find info regarding looping through excel sheets or pulling the same range of data from excel, but not both. I was able to import the specific cells of data I needed by using `select * from [Jan Pick Up$A6:P57]`, but can't figure out how to apply that to a loop.

Comment: A three minute google got me this. http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-read-multiple-sheets-from-excel.html Please try and respond with any issues.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, yes that works for basic looping to bring in all excel sheets. However, I need to do this as well as only select _specific_ cells from each of those sheets.

Comment: If I understand correctly you just need to dynamically insert the sheet name into your final select statement. Is that your issue?

Comment: Basically in step 3 of that guide, you use your SQL statement (without the sheet name in it) and it should work. If not, please post back with an explanation of the issue.